# How to get text label in input type radio?

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I made a custom radio input like this.
When selected, How do I get the value of the text label in the radio type input and bring it into the Syntax hyperlinks "Order Link"?

```js
let result = document.querySelector('#result');
  document.body.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let message;
    switch (target.id) {
      case '30day':
        message = 'selected 30d package';
        break;
      case '6month':
        message = 'selected 6m package';
        break;
      case '1year':
        message = 'selected 1y package';
        break;
                     }
    result.textContent = message;
  });
```

```css
body {
  background:#2d2d2d;
  display:block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding:0;
  margin:20;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
}

.select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.option {
  padding: 0 30px 0 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  border-top: #222 solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  order: 2;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.option:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.select:focus .option {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: all;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
}

input:checked+label {
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #666;
  border-top: none;
  position: relative;
}

input:checked+label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

input:checked+label:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  content: '';
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<!-- custom radio selected -->
 <div class="select" style="margin:20px;" tabindex="1">
  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="" checked>
  <label for="" class="option">Select package</label>

  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="30day">
  <label for="30day" class="option">30 d package</label>

  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="6month">
  <label for="6month" class="option">6 m package</label>

  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="1year">
  <label for="1year" class="option">1 y package</label>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <!-- selected text result -->
 <p id="result" style="color:#fff;"></p>
 <!-- Order Link -->
 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123456789&text=Hello%20I%20want%20to%20order%20(this is the package label value text)
" target="_blank">order link</a>
```

In additional to, how do I create a variable for multiple phone numbers in javascript that works to be a random number every time a web page is opened or refreshed the phone number in the `"Order Link"` hyperlinks section `"send?phone=123456789"` will change randomly.

What I mean by random phone numbers are pre-defined ones, for example there are 5 choices of phone numbers to be randomized every time web page is opened or refreshed for eg random number is: `"123456789,1987654321,122334455,112233445,165456781"`
and it seems better with the warning text shown on

```
<p id="result" style="color:#fff;"></p>
```

if `"order link"` clicked but custom selected not selected before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can get the label of the radio by getting its `for` attribute which equals the id of the radio.

Also, I add a function to generate random numbers with specific length to generate the phone number.

I used `encodeURIComponent` to encode the `text` query parameter because there are spaces in it.

```js
const getRandomPhoneNumber = () => {
  const phoneNumbers = ["123456789", "1987654321", "122334455",               "112233445", "165456781"]
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (phoneNumbers.length))
  return phoneNumbers[randomIndex]
}

const phoneNumber = getRandomPhoneNumber()
let result = document.querySelector('#result');
const link = document.querySelector('#link');
const warning = document.querySelector('#warning');
const url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send";
let changed = false;

const updateLink = (message) => {
  let newUrl = url;
  result.textContent = message;
  newUrl += `?phone=${phoneNumber}`
  newUrl += `?text=${encodeURIComponent(`Hello I want to order ${message}`)}`
  link.href = newUrl
}

updateLink('')

document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  changed = true;
  warning.innerText = '';
  let target = e.target;
  const label = document.querySelector(`[for='${target.id}']`)
  let message = label.innerText;
  updateLink(message)
});
  
  
link.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!changed) {
    warning.innerText = 'You need to select a package.'
    return;
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background:#2d2d2d;
  display:block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding:0;
  margin:20;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
}

.select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.option {
  padding: 0 30px 0 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  border-top: #222 solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  order: 2;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.option:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.select:focus .option {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: all;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
}

input:checked+label {
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #666;
  border-top: none;
  position: relative;
}

input:checked+label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

input:checked+label:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  content: '';
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<!-- custom radio selected -->
 <div class="select" id="select" style="margin:20px;" tabindex="1">
  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="" checked>
  <label for="" class="option">Select package</label>

  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="30day">
  <label for="30day" class="option">30 d package</label>

  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="6month">
  <label for="6month" class="option">6 m package</label>

  <input class="selectopt" name="package" type="radio" id="1year">
  <label for="1year" class="option">1 y package</label>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <!-- selected text result -->
 <p id="result" style="color:#fff;"></p>
 <p id="warning" style="color:#FFA500;"></p>
 <!-- Order Link -->
 <a id="link" href="" target="_blank">order link</a>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks this is a very good answer! I have a little mistake in writing. What I mean by random phone numbers are pre-defined ones, for example there are 5 choices of phone numbers to be randomized "123456789,1987654321,122334455,112233445,165456781" and it seems better with the warning text shown on " <p id="result" style="color:#fff;"></p>" if "order link" clicked but custom selected not selected before.

Comment: Hello @MaruliDavin, You are welcome, I just updated the answer with your new needs, please check.

Comment: Helo @Mina, Thanks  You are amazing, this is very helpful. After I tried it there was a little error when not selecting the radio but "order link" on clicking it still took me to the default link. Random Phone Number works, but I hope it only changes when the web is opened or the web page is referred, in the above code it changes every time I select a radio.

As for "<p id="result" style="color:#fff;"></p>" it shouldn't take the radio label value, just leave it as before as it's desirable for custom text.

Comment: Hello @MaruliDavin, You are welcome, I'm happy to help you, but you are a developer, so you can use my code and make these small changes easily, I provide you with the concepts and the solutions for the hard parts, these small tweaks you can overcome easily, Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Mina, Thanks again! I've fixed some needed parts. The code you wrote runs very well, I'm just a little confused to generate random numbers when the first page is opened or refreshed.

Comment: You are welcome, I just update it for you, Remember to add this `script` at the end of the `body`, because it does change in the `DOM` when it loaded.

Comment: Hi @Mina Thank you every code you wrote runs very well, Extraordinary!